# String and character sequence error (force close) Android

Tags: android, image

I am facing a problem in solving this issue.

I have 30 smiley images. In a grid view I display all the 30 images. So when I select the image based on the position of the image, the corresponding special character will be displayed from SQLite DB. Before I send message to service it is like "hi :)". What I need is to replace the ":)" with the corresponding smiley image in the local folder of my project (eg. R.drawable.facea.png). I am able to fetch the data and replace ":)" with "aaaaa"(example). But when I try to replace the ":)" with Char Sequence (Image), I get 'force close error'.   Where am I going wrong?

I have a function to draw image and I get image as in Character Sequence. How can I use the value in this function globally. I also tried to create a global variable and use the CS value globally. But I still get 'force close error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a span (specifically an ImageSpan) to be able to embed  bitmap in a string. I have written about this on [my blog](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177) which also covers some common pitfalls.

If you still cannot get it to work I would suggest posting the precise details of what is going wrong: i.e. your code, and the stacktrace that is getting dumped to logcat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback sir. My entire code is available in this link. http://pastebin.com/dj1xXcLN. Kindly look into my code and tell me how can i make replace my specialcharcter coming from web service with my smiley images. I am able to replace the specialcharcter with some string values like i can replace "hi :)" with "hi aaaaa". But when i try to replace ":)" with a image i get force close error. Can you please guide me in this issue.

Comment: Without the requested stacktrace of the error it is almost impossible to find.

Comment: I would point out, however, that the `getView()` method of your inaccurately named `EfficientAdapter` class will cause you major problems. `getView()`needs to be as lean and fast as possible, yet you are performing network calls and XML parsing in it. That's not necessarily the cause of this specific problem, but is indicative of some fairly fundamental problems in your implementation.